# PHP (OOP) - get an object from function is called

Tags: php, algorithm, oop

I'm new to the OOP model of PHP and encountered a problem recently.
When Object B is thrown in Object A and calls a function of B, is it possible to get Object A inside the function of B?

Consider the following code example:

```
    $test = new A();

    class A
    {
        public function __construct () {
            $arg = "something";
            try{
                throw new B($arg);
            }
            catch (B $e) {
                $e->bar();
            }
        }
        public function foo($arg){
            //do something
        }
    }

    class B extends Exception
    {
        public $arg;
        public function __construct ($arg) {
            $this->arg = $arg;
        }
        public function bar(){
            // do something
            // .....

            // this is not correct, $this is not object A
            // so how do i do this?
            $this->foo($arg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is you intention to do?

Comment: I'm adding error handling to a existing system, so I can't really change the whole thing. But thanks for your efforts here.  @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev 's answer is good enough for me.

Comment: no problem, it's good to me too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a caller object into a constructor:

```
throw new B($this);
```

Your B constructor will place it into $arg:

```
public $arg; // better call it $caller or somewhat
public function __construct ($arg) {
    $this->arg = $arg;
}
```

Then, in a method of B you can access it:

```
public function bar(){
    $this->arg->foo(""); // pass an argument, which is expected at function foo($arg){}
}
```

Here is the working [IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/XrUuea).
Also, @Sumurai8 has implemented a good [PHPFiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/es7f-3ry2). It extends your constructor so that it passes both argument and caller.

Comment: A phpfiddle with, more or less this implemented, can be found [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/es7f-3ry2). The code in this answer seems correct to me.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Very clear and specific!
I learn a lot about OOP from all of your comments. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best approach, as you assume that Exception B is thrown from the class that have method `foo`, which may not alway be the case.

I would recommend to keep it simple:

```
$test = new A();

class A
{
    public function __construct () {
        $arg = "something";
        try{
            throw new B($arg);
        }
        catch (B $e) {
            $e->bar();
            $this->foo($arg);
        }
    }
    public function foo($arg){
        //do something
    }
}

class B extends Exception
{
    public $arg;
    public function __construct ($arg) {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }
    public function bar(){
        // do something
        // .....

        // this is correct now
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make my example clear. the return value of $this->foo($arg) is needed in the bar() function. Anyway, I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: np, nothing stops you to pass the the result to the function `$e->bar($this->foo($arg));` tho.

Comment: Yap, you are right. But I also need to call $this->foo($arg) several times.... so in that case it might be a mess. However, I think your point is important, so I'll think about that and see if I can change the whole structure to improve my work. Thanks for mention that :)